# How to fly a departure after a practice approach with Garmin GTN750?

Tags: approach, ifr-navigation, departure-sid

I fly a C172 which is equipped with a Garmin GTN750. Whenever I shoot a practice approach followed by a published departure I run in sequencing problems. So I load and activate the approach and load the departure. As soon as I hit the runway the system asks for the missed approach which I don't wanna fly. But neither the system starts sequencing towards the loaded departure nor am I able to activate a leg of the departure manually ("activate leg" is greyed out in the flight plan submenu). I have to delete the entire flight plan and reload the departure to make it work? But why? How to do better? Is there any recommended best practice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I found out:

I asked Garmin Support but their answer was disappointing. They said "it's normally the case that the departure is loaded on the ground as a way to leave your departure airport rather than an alternative to flying a missed approach, so this seems to be an irregular operation which may result in weird quirks for the system." Irregular operation? That has happened multiple times to me and it's always the case if your climb out after a practice approach is a published procedure instead of a radar vectors.

Garmin's solution is "Deleting the flight plan is an effective solution to resolving problems where the GTN wants to fly the missed approach."

Referring to the greyed out waypoints on the departure they said: "Departure procedures may involve a grey waypoint because there is an emphasis on hand flying the aircraft when departing an airport. I would recommend flying to the first waypoint manually, and then activating the route to the next available waypoint." That doesn't make sense at all and it's not a good recommendation either.

Here is what chatGPT came up with. Its answer was surprisingly good and helpful. I have verified its answer and it works:

1. Prepare a follow on flight plan and save it. As soon as you are overhead the runway (or later) load the stored flightplan. Sequencing works as expected.
2. Alternatively without preparing a new flight plan: Just switch to the flight plan menu where your departure is already loaded. Select the next applicable waypoint on the departure, hit "direct to" and "activate". Obviously for the first "direct to" portion your are technically not flying the departure procedure but should be close enough for most cases. After reaching the waypoint sequencing works as expected.